# Firefox sync service

Tags: firefox, sync

I have reinstalled Firefox (Windows 10 x64) and activated the sync service. 
I don't get back synced material.

I installed both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Can I check whether the new installation somehow deleted everything on Mozilla's servers or it is still there?
I am mostly interested to bookmarks.
Can I manually download them from Firefox service?

Comment: Questions about browser functionality belong on [su].